# How to get selected words of string?

Tags: php, split

I have this string:

```
$data = "175/80R14 88T VEC 4SEASONS G2 (oprijem B , gorivo E , hrup 67)";
```

Now I want words from 88T to (oprijem...
so I must get **VEC 4SEASONS G2**

But this 175/80R14 88T is different everytime...as well as lengh of words which I want out...

Some examples more:

295/40R20 106V SP WI SPT 4D MS N0 MFS (oprijem C , gorivo E , hrup 73)
this: SP WI SPT 4D MS N0 MFS

225/65R17 106H ESKIMO SUV 2 XL (oprijem B , gorivo C , hrup 72)
this:  ESKIMO SUV 2 XL

Thank you

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use next simple code:

```
<?php
$data = "175/80R14 88T VEC 4SEASONS G2 (oprijem B , gorivo E , hrup 67)";
// split row to words
$words = explode(' ', $data);

// cut off 2 first words and concatenate array to string
$result = implode(' ', array_slice($words,2));

print_r($result);
```

[Live PHP code here](https://phpize.online/?phpses=b276c3f26d0a8a6aee3e81a75823cd81&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql57)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex:

```
preg_match('/^[^ ]+ ([^\(]+)/', $data, $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Slava Rozhnev and BadHorsie. I combine your codes and get the answer :)

```
$words = explode(' ', $data);

$result = implode(' ', array_slice($words,2));

preg_match('/([^\(]+)/', $result, $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```